# using vector::erase for the whole range

Tags: c++, vector

Is

```
v.erase(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Just as fast as

```
v.clear();
```

?

I don't care about little overheads such as extra function calls etc, the compiler will inline that stuff.

The reason I ask is because I have code like the following:

```
v.erase(v.begin(), last_it);
```

last_it will usually be the end iterator, but not always. I know that erasing a vector not from the end has a cost, because later elements in the vector will need to be copied down. In the case where last_it is not the end iterator (rare), I can live with that. But I don't want to introduce such overhead when I basically want to clear the vector. So I considered writing my code like this:

```
if (last_it == v.end())
{
    v.clear();
}
else
{
    v.erase(v.begin(), last_it);
}
```

I would like to know whether this is necessary to avoid a performance penalty for erasing the whole vector. I would prefer to keep my code clear and use a single-line statement if there is no penalty.

Comment: Why not look at your implementation code? You might well find this `void clear() { erase(begin(), end()); }`

Answer (score 8):

Looking into the sourcecode of vector (refering to visual studio 2012 (code snippet below) or [SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_vector.h) (line 434) one), `clear` is defined as:

```
void clear() _NOEXCEPT
{   // erase all elements
    erase(begin(), end());
}
```

So i guess yes.

So in your case, I wouldn't use the if statement, and just do:

```
v.erase(v.begin(), last_it);
```

Comment: Not all standard libraries implement it in this way. For example I once worked with one where `clear` freed the memory while `erase` did not (now I can't speak if that's a conforming implementation or not)

Comment: I am using VS2013 whose library code is undecipherable to me.

Comment: @NeilKirk: In VS2012 when you call `erase()` with `begin()` and `end()` iterators it just calls `clear()`. Either way you are over-thinking this, do what is most clear in your code and don't try to beat the compiler (or library).

Comment: @MarkB sure you are right. the best way is to look into his own libs, but making the code portable also could eliminate this approach, since other environment's using different implementaions of the std::libs. however, i guess this implementation of clear was for a system where memory is a expensive resource?

Comment: @MarkB so? If it really bothers you, you can (`shrink_to_fit` | `reserve`) right afterwards, and sometimes have a happy no-op.

Comment: @Caleth The question was "Will `erase(begin, end)` be as fast as `clear`?" and I was just pointing out an implementation where `clear` would be slower.

Answer (score 8):

Don't worry about this and write the obvious code using `erase`. If you erase to the end there won't be any elements left to shift down so there should be minimal performance difference between the two, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there isn't a single answer to your question, because there is no single implementation of the C++ standard library that is used on all platforms. The only thing that is specified by the standard is the [algorithmic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of the clear operation. Specifically, it can be constant time for trivially-destructible types; for types that require destruction, it will be linear in the number of destructions. That's the only guarantee that you get from the C++ standard.

The standard library is typically distributed as part of your compiler installation, so exact implementation details like this could very well vary from compiler to compiler. If you're only concerned with one single compiler version, you can come up with an answer, but recognize that it is subject to change if you ever change platforms.